# The annotation "@ODM\Document" in class ... was never imported

Tags: mongodb, annotations, doctrine-odm

**Annotation doesn't work any more after upgrading php7.4 to 8.1**.

I upgrade a php7.4 project to php8.1.9, then annotations don't work:

> The annotation "@ODM\Document" in class ... was never imported.

Some examples of annotations are:

```
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 * @Annotation\Name("client")
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"novalidate": "true"})
 */
```

I have checked the above two classes exist under vendor/.
I have also run `composer dumpautoload`.

There also exist AnnotationDriver of Doctrine:

```
vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php;

vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php
```

In addition, the version of their packages are not changed.

My questions:

- Firstly what's the most effective way to make the system work or identify problems ?
- I'm considering, do I have to replace all the annotations to PHP8 attributes ? But this doesn't look necessary or practical. There're huge amount of annotations. Even if I can replace those annotations of my project, the vendor packages still use annotations and definitely I can't change them.
- Just wondering, which version of Doctrine Mongodb ODM support PHP8 attributes ?
- Just guessing, is it because PHP8 makes the current Zend framework 2 and Doctrine ODM broken and thus causing annotation not work any more? If so, how to fix?

The related packages are as the following:

- "zendframework/zendframework" : "2.3.10"
- "doctrine/annotations" : "1.2.8",
- "doctrine/mongodb": "1.2.2" (There's no version for PHP8, so I have to install it as github VCS package )
- "mongodb/mongodb" : "^1.0.1",
- "doctrine/mongodb-odm" : "1.0.0-BETA14",
- "doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module" : "0.8.0",
- "doctrine/annotations" : "1.2.8",
- "doctrine/common": "2.4.4",
- "doctrine/doctrine-module": "0.8.2",

If you need further resources, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Your dependencies are seriously outdated and using them with PHP 8.x is asking for troubles. You should work on updating them first.

Comment: Also, attributes are supported since ODM 2.3.0: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/releases/tag/2.3.0